# Keep a pointer to a callback even when navigating to a new page in a popup window

Tags: javascript, callback, showmodaldialog

I'm working on a project which insists on using real modal windows. The current implementation works, it simply calls "showModalDialog" and uses the result that the dialog stores in "returnVal".

However, on Chrome, when you navigate to a different page, this functionality no longer works. It's a documented bug.

I'm changing it to use window.open. I can pass in a callback no problem... However, the popup window needs to be navigatable (it's to add an item to a DB, then return the items ID to the calling page). I can pass the callback in to the popup window, but when it navigates, I lose that callback...

Is there any way I can keep a pointer to a callback even when navigating to a new page in a popup window?

Answer (score 1):

Open a frameset in the dialog, and in the frameset load the page in a frame.

When you navigate to the next page, it will be inside the frame, so the frameset stays the same and the `returnVal` is intact. You can access the return value using `parent.returnVal` from the frame.

Comment: Hmm, I can see how this could work... It has the negatives [hiding the pages real url, being a frame (i hate frames), adding another request to the modals load time]. I suppose I could do the same thing with an AJAX call instead of a real POST, too, but then I need a backend. So aside from AJAX / Frames, can you think of any other solutions? Can you pass a javascript callback through a POST?

Comment: @DanRedux: I can't think of a different way to keep the reference. You can only pass information in the form of text between pages.

Comment: Do you think it might be possible to pass a string of JS that is passed through while navigating, and then eval'd?

Comment: @DanRedux: Yes, you could, but that would't help. Any identifiers in the code wouldnt mean the same thing any more.